# Sending SAML request with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, saml-2.0

I am using Symfony2 and I have to Connect my user through SSO to another service using Saml Request , in this Case we are the Service provider , from what i gathered ; once the user hit the link im supposed to redirect him to the bridge with a Saml request having the data so he can be authenticated , but i don't know which bundle to install or how to send a Saml request in the first place .
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 alternatives here:

- Use bundles based on [php-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) like [OneloginSamlBundle](https://github.com/hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle)
- Use bundles based on [simplesamlphp](https://simplesamlphp.org) like [SimplesamlphpBundle](https://github.com/hslavich/SimplesamlphpBundle)
- Use [SamlSPBundle](https://github.com/aerialship/SamlSPBundle), a bundle based on [lightsaml](https://github.com/aerialship/lightsaml)

If you decide to use OneloginSamlBundle, the AuthNRequest is sent from the SP to the IdP when the SP-initiated SSO happens.

[Resources/config/routing.yml](https://github.com/hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing.yml) defines the SAML routes. /saml/login will initiates the SSO process.

When you access /saml/login the [loginAction](https://github.com/hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle/blob/master/Controller/SamlController.php#L10) defined on the SamlController.php happens and an AuthNrequest is sent to the IdP SSO url, and a SAMLResponse is expected at the SP on the ACS endpoint. That SAMLResponse is the one that will contain user attributes in order to SSO or provision that user on symfony2 app.

Comment: Thank you for your response i installed OneLoginSaml but i didnt know how to actually create a SAML request i found a \Onelogin...:builder() but i dndn't know tow things :
1) where do i put user informations ? is it in contact or attributes ? and how do i actually make the SAML request ?
Thank you again

Comment: Thank you for your explanation smartin just to recapitulate from my side as a SP i send the saml request with the user data to the bridge and wait for the saml response is that it ?

Comment: You dont sent user data...you sent a authnrequest, a login form (from the idp) is present to the user. It logs in the IdP and then the IdP sends the SAMLResponse.